# Java scanner array input until end of line

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I want to input some integers with space delimiter from console, press Enter and then read them into List. (Initially, I don't know the number of the integers and I don't want to parse strings)

Is it possible?

Comment: Flagging to close this question as it's too broad. Please attempt to actually code out your solution instead of just asking SO "give me code please." Try this, post some code samples if it doesn't work and then someone will help.

Comment: Is it possible, yes.

Comment: while loop, scanner.hasnext(), Integer.parseint(), if variable.equals(""), break.

Comment: @Zizouz212 is it possible to do it without  Integer.parseint() using just scanner.nextInt()?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        a = scanner.next();
        if (a.equals(""))
            break;
        b = Integer.parseInt(a);
        list.add(b);
```

or:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(a);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
```

You can initialize everything yourself. Just a basis to help you :)

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class help {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            if (scnr.hasNextInt() == false)
                break;

            int a = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }}
```

You'll have to figure out a way to detect an empty line in scanner though. I can't think of a way right now.

Comment: hasNext() returns boolean. I think you mean next().
But I do understand how to do it using parseInt.
The second solution doesn't work, becouse the loop doesn't interrupt when I press enter.

Comment: That's right. :) But thanks for reminding me you can use `hasnext()`

Comment: Unfortunately, the third code doesn't work.
It seems that it's impossible to solve this problem without next() (or even nextLine()) and parseInt() after this.

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int a = 0;
    a = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    int count = String.valueOf(a).length();

    for(int i = 0; i< count ; i++){ 
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a).substring(i, i+1)));

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)